# Use media keys to switch keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, gui

I have a keyboard with a whole lot of media keys and hardly use any of them but for volume - so how do I set some of them to switch between layouts? E.g. use "next track" to switch to Russian, and "previous track" to English. I couldn't find options like `grp:caps_toggle` for `setxkbmap` which would achieve this.

Comment: Use `xev` and `evtest` to find out as what keycodes/keysyms they show up. Very likely you need your own xkbd definition, read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058). Yes, it's complicated.

Comment: In addition to the article from @dirkt, here's my laundry list of related resources:
https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/769644-hacking-your-linux-keyboard-with-xkb
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Configuration